# How to write condition on report count variable in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

My problem is I want Report_Count variable to be null if it increases to 28. so for any value greater than 28 it will become null.
I have written this condition in print when expression property of Report Count variable

```
($V{REPORT_COUNT} > 28) ? $V{REPORT_COUNT} = null : $V{REPORT_COUNT}
```

Is it valid or it contains any errors? I don't know why it is not working.....
Any help would be appreciable.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the built-in `REPORT_COUNT` variable, as far as I know, you cannot change its value. You could, however, define your own variable, for instance `MY_REPORT_COUNT`, and print it in your textfield.

For the variable class type - choose for example `Integer`.
For the variable expression:

```
$V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() > 28 ? null : $V{REPORT_COUNT}
```